# How can I fit a square HTML image inside a circle border?

Tags: html, css

I have a square image, and I'd like to put it inside a circle border. How can I make it so that the entire image fits instead of its corners getting cut?

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png');
    background-size: contain;   
}
```

Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsoegijono/Cb2LB/).

Comment: Your image has transparent border/space around it. Remove that and it will fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to shrink the image slightly to make it fit within the circle. To calculate the exact size, divide the diameter of the circle by sqrt(2). In this case, 200px / sqrt(2) is about 141px.

Thus, add the following properties:

```
background-size: 141px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb2LB/7/)

Note that the blue block doesn't touch the circle because the image has a transparent border.

**UPDATE:** As [cassiorenan correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843805/1127114), using a percentage allows the image to automatically scale if you change the size of the circle. Since 1 / sqrt(2) = 0.707..., you can use 70.7% instead of 141px:

```
background-size: 70.7%;
```

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. This is how you correctly fit a square in to a circle.

Comment: Tested and working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the background size to a percentage(So it will still have the same relative size ragardless of you changing the circle's width/height.) and center it. While you're at it, tell it to not repeat.
On your particular case, this code works:

```
    .circle {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png');
        background-size: 90%;   
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
    }
```

Edit: Fixed code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you must remove transparent border/space around the image or if you don't wanna do that then use this CSS

```
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png') center;
  background-size: 130%;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the background a size like `background-size: 100px;` then position it in the center of the div and tell it not to repeat:

```
        background-size: 100px;
        background-position:50%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

The coding should now look like this:

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png') ;
    background-size: 100px;   
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Cb2LB/8/)